# Dúvida filtro com linq, ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, query, mvc

Estou com uma dúvida em um filtro usando Linq, 
Tenho um objeto critica
Dentro de crítica tem um ienumerable
Preciso retornar uma lista de criticas que o status do  ultimo movimentocritica for igual a 2
Porém o código abaixo está dando erro

```asp
var Criticas = from a in Db.Criticas select a; 
Criticas = Criticas.Where(c => c.MovimentacoesCritica.LastOrDefault().Status.Equals(2));
```

Comment: li vinte vezes e nao entendi a sua dúvida! :D

Comment: Você disse que está com uma dúvida, mostrou um pouco de código e deu uma explicadinha básica no que você está tentando fazer. Mas no fim, você não disse qual é a dúvida afinal!

Comment: Você quer obter o ultimo registro com o status igual a 2? Tá bem confuso.

Comment: Está muito confuso... Você deseja pegar o ultimo item da lista quando o mesmo possui status igual a 2? ou deseja pegar o ultimo da lista que esteja com status 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulei seu código no LinqPad com Lists e Enumerable e funcionou corretamente, provavelmente o problema está porque a sua query (`var Criticas = from a in Db.Criticas select a;`)retorna um objeto IQueryable e ao chamar o Where ele não consegue processar o LastOrDefault para um novo IQueryable.

Tente converter Criticas para `List` ou `Enumerable`

```
var Criticas = (from a in Db.Criticas select a).ToList();
    var ListCriticas = Criticas.Where(c => c.MovimentacoesCritica.LastOrDefault(o => o.Status.Equals(2)) != null);
```

Comment: dá o seguinte erro: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Valor não pode ser nulo.

Comment: O correto aí seria: `c.MovimentacoesCritica.LastOrDefault(e => e.Status.Equals(2))`

Comment: @KleberBarros, deve ser que o LastOrDefault esta retornando null porque não tem nenhum item na lista. o LastOrDefault gera este null quando não existem itens na lista.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira, realmente, vou editar a resposta, isso vai até resolver a questão de lista vazia que o Kleber comentou. vlw

Comment: Continua dando ArgumentNullException

Comment: @KleberBarros O campo Status aceita valores nulos? pode ser que algum item da lista esta com a propriedade nula e neste caso o .Equals lança exceção tente mudar a condição para (o => o.Status != null && o.Status.Equals(2))